# Connecting an iOS app to a database using Swift, SlimPHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, swift, slim

I have a website setup, where users can register, and that data is stored into a database. My website is built using SlimPHP along with some other dependencies, such as twig. Is there a dependancy that I can use to help connect my iOS app to my database so users can log in? Or, how could I go about linking my app to the database. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Develop a RestApi on your webserver and that Api will connect your app with Database you have. Then your app will need to interact with that RestApi. [Here](http://devdactic.com/rest-api-parse-json-swift/) is a nice tutorial to connect swift IOS app with RestApi which return JSON response.

Comment: Ok thanks. The one thing I was confused on is how to generate a baseUrl that has all the users. In the tutorial they have a random generator, with the data, but how do you get that file from a database on the website?

Comment: do you need to sign In through API ? if yes then it will be a lot risky to get all the users to client app and then process the login request. You need to see "how to build RestApi with php", google it. Login Api will be first thing in every tutorial mostly.